# The property 'Id' is part of the object's key information and cannot be modified after the second insert

Tags: entity-framework, c#-4.0

I have a table with Id as primary key

The model generated by EF is this

```
public partial class Home_Orchard_Users_UserPartRecord
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string NormalizedUserName { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public string PasswordFormat { get; set; }
    public string HashAlgorithm { get; set; }
    public string PasswordSalt { get; set; }
    public string RegistrationStatus { get; set; }
    public string EmailStatus { get; set; }
    public string EmailChallengeToken { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> CreatedUtc { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> LastLoginUtc { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> LastLogoutUtc { get; set; }
}
```

When I tried to insert a data from a list, the first insert was okay but the second one I got error: The property 'Id' is part of the object's key information and cannot be modified.

```
      foreach (var ContentItem in ListContentItem)
                {



                    ContentItemData.Data = ContentItem.Data;
                    ContentItemData.ContentType_id = 3;
                    Context.Home_Orchard_Framework_ContentItemRecord.Add(ContentItemData);
                    Context.SaveChanges();
                    int Return_Id = ContentItemData.Id;

                    UserData.Id = Return_Id;
                    UserData.UserName = ContentItem.UserName;
                    UserData.Email = ContentItem.Email;
                    UserData.NormalizedUserName = ContentItem.NormalizedUserName;
                    UserData.Password = "AMQ6a4CzqeyLbWqrd7EwoaTV23fopf++3FpcBlV+Gsvgja3Ye3LwFlXVHyhAcWyKaw==";
                    UserData.PasswordFormat = "Hashed";
                    UserData.HashAlgorithm = "PBKDF2";
                    UserData.PasswordSalt = "FaED9QsIV9HD95m8FO5OSA==";
                    UserData.RegistrationStatus = "Approved";
                    UserData.EmailStatus = "Approved";
                    UserData.CreatedUtc = DateTime.Today;
                    Context.Home_Orchard_Users_UserPartRecord.Add(UserData);
                    //Context.SaveChanges();

                    i = i + 1;

                    progress = ((float)i / nCount) * 100;
                    Console.Write("\r{0}%", progress);
                    Thread.Sleep(50);
                }
```

Why I can't insert the second time? The Id is the primary key and it's not autogenerated so it has to be input manually.

Comment: Its unclear where you create UserData. It should be created in foreach scope, otherwise you will add UserData first time, and update all other times (but updates fails because you cant change object's key information)

Comment: You seem to be reusing one and the same object instances `ContentItemData` and `UserData`. Try using `var ... = new ...` inside the loop.